# AWS boto3: see proof that client is using transfer acceleration endpoint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to enable Transfer Acceleration for some AWS S3 buckets.

I start up my client session:

```py
client = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id=environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
        aws_secret_access_key=environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    )
```

Then I turn Transfer Acceleration on through the S3 console, and have ensured it is enabled and turned on in the code as such:

```
response = client.put_bucket_accelerate_configuration(
    Bucket='string',
    AccelerateConfiguration={
        'Status': 'Enabled'
    }
)
```

and

```
response = client.get_bucket_accelerate_configuration(
    Bucket='string'
)
```

both snippets come straight from boto3 docs. I am able to upload to the bucket successfully later on in the code with:

```py
client.upload_fileobj(data, environ.get("AWS_S3_BUCKET"), 'key')
```

I tried setting the `endpoint_url` param while starting the client session, but this just created a new folder (with my bucket title) inside my bucket.

It seems that boto3 is the only SDK that doesn't have some sort of "use transfer acceleration endpoint" flag. I know it is enabled on the bucket, and I have proof of that, but I have no proof that it is ***actually using the endpoint***.

I've tried going through client metadata, bucket metadata, and every other client method that returns any sort of data, and I can't find proof that it actually used the acceleration endpoint.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried enabling verbose logging in boto3? It might log which domain it's using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Connect to S3 accelerate endpoint with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52957679/174777)  mentions using:

```
Config(s3={"use_accelerate_endpoint": True})
```

This parameter is listed in [Config Reference — botocore documentation](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html):

> **s3 (dict)**
>
> `use_accelerate_endpoint` -- Refers to whether to use the S3 Accelerate endpoint. The value must be a boolean. If True, the client will use the S3 Accelerate endpoint. If the S3 Accelerate endpoint is being used then the addressing style will always be virtual.

So try using:

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3", config=Config(s3={"use_accelerate_endpoint": True}))
```